# Wrong version of ssl being used when running python 3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl

I'm running a code in python 3 using urlopen():

```
url = "http://www.ksl.com"

import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
html = html.decode('utf-8')
```

Every time I run it, it pops an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1260, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 377, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 988, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH TO SCRIPT", line 59, in <module>
    html = urlopen(req).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 504, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 696, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1256, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)>
```

Looking at similar threads, I've deduced that the version of SSL being used in conjunction with python is probably wrong, however, I haven't been able to solve the problem, and I don't have enough know how to do it myself.

The thing that is weird to me is I haven't changed anything about my computer, and the script was running fine last week!

What gives?

Comment: If nothing changed on your computer, the server may have been updated to be more strict (disallowing known-insecure protocols). Since you aren't naming a specific server this is reproducible against, we can't investigate whether that's the case.

Comment: Really, to be solvable, this should have a reproducer -- the shortest possible code that produces the same error. Which `ssl_version` you're using matters here quite a lot; the default of `SSLv23` should be compatible with pretty much everything. **If**, of course, you're correct that it really is a version compatibility mismatch; there's not enough information in this question as currently written to provide solid evidence either way.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response Charles, I have updated the question so that the problem I am experiencing may be accurately reproduced.

Comment: Interesting -- running against my local Python 3.6.2 install linked against OpenSSL 1.0.2l, the code you've provided works perfectly. Could you please provide the value of `__import__('ssl').OPENSSL_VERSION`? (I also have a MacPorts install of Python 3.5.4, and it doesn't reproduce there either).

Comment: ...although I do note that the reproducer has a HTTP -- not HTTPS -- address; is that correct?

Comment: The value provided there is what tipped me off to the difference of SSL's being used - I should have provided that info. The value it gives is: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016            However when I run openssl version in terminal I get: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017

Comment: Yes, the URL is correct

Comment: There've been quite a lot of security updates between January 2016 and now -- you should **really** try to get something linked against a newer binary. How was your Python interpreter installed? (MacPorts? Homebrew? Something else?)

Comment: Man, this website can be a pain. I would like to take this conversation to chat, however I don't have a high enough reputation to do so. Not sure how that makes sense... Anyhow, I'm not sure how it was installed. I initially was using python via anaconda and jupyter notebooks, however, I have switched to just using python via the terminal. If I had to guess, it was installed using python's website.

Comment: ...so, I'd suggest using a package manager (like one of the ones I mentioned above -- personally, I think the MacPorts security model makes more sense than the Homebrew one, but there are smart and reasonable people on both sides of that debate; it's a question of which kind of threat one's most worried about). That way getting newer versions of software you installed is a one- or two-command operation across however many programs you have installed.

Comment: So your advice to solve this problem is to install MacPorts and use that to update my python packages?

Comment: It'd be installing a separate of Python packages, plus its own OpenSSL. You'd want to either remove the manually-installed one or just make sure the MacPorts one comes earlier in the PATH (which the docs cover). But that's a fairly decent starting point -- would get you onto current binaries so we don't need to worry about problems specific to whatever random software versions you happen to be running.

Comment: So I was able to successfully install MacPorts, however using the documentation for MacPorts I haven't been able to effectively upgrade my openssl version (I keep checking it inline in my python code, as I showed you above)

Comment: Do you have any ideas of how to proceed Charles? I'm stumped :(